# Как загружать данные в функциональных компонентах с использованием?

Tags: react-native, react-hook

не могу разобраться где и когда можно осуществлять сетевые запросы в функциональных компонентах с использованием хуков?
подскажите пожалуйста )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В React всякие загрузки из вне можно делать в componentDidMount, в хуках его аналогом является useEffect. НО равнозначным только если вторым параметром будет пустое множество:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch()............................
},[]); ///вот оно пустое множество
```

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

тогда ЭТОТ useEffect сработает только при старте. Для остальных создайте отдельный useEffect.